# external SD card unmounted lost everything

Tags: external-sd

I unmounted my SD card before resetting my phone when put baxk in nothing came up. No pictures or music. I have a Galaxy S3. Can I retrieve them some how?

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me and afterwards i found all my photos, videos, etc. were in a folder on the sd card called LOST.DIR. To make it more difficult unfortunately the file extensions were removed and the file names were meaningless e.g. 'holiday.mpeg' became '1g2h3j4k5'.

Check for this folder then copy it's contents to your laptop or whatever. You can see the file sizes and you know what you had on there so try something like adding a .mpeg extension to the large files and .jpeg to the smaller ones.
It took me some time to get them all back but in the end i got through it.